# First time using heroku, I get nothing but "Heroku client internal error."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have installed the heroku toolbelt following these instructions:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#set-up

However, when I try 'heroku create', I get this:

!    Heroku client internal error.

```
Error:       undefined method `netrc_filename' for Netrc:Class (NoMethodError)
Command:     heroku create
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.42.25 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
Error ID:    c331e7026ad348e8a75433bb34b4634e
```

I've tried reinstalling the heroku toolbelt, but can't figure out why it's still not working. I'd really appreciate any advice!

Thanks.

Comment: What is the Version of your heroku cli client? I have faced similar problem before, I uninstalled my system ruby and heroku client, reinstalled them both, and it simply worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Heroku, and then deleting the Heroku directory if it still exists.
This worked for me; I had the same error and the first reinstall did not help.

The underlying problem could be the one pointed out by webbtj here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1853